# Cannot print a scanned document

Tags: printing, pdf, scanner, gimp

Ubuntu 20.04, all up to date.

I just scanned a page using the Ubuntu standard Scan-app and a Canon LiDE 110 and saved it as a .png and .pdf.

I have a Brother HL-L2340D printer that is working fine with GIMP, Xed etc. It will not print the scanned document in either .pdf or .png format. I have checked Permissions and the sole User has Read/Write including group. The Owner is the sole User.

I loaded it into GIMP and it shows "Printing," then "print completed" but nothing comes out. I can load in a .jpg of something else to GIMP and it prints that fine, just not the scanned one.

I converted it to Grayscale in GIMP and still nothing.

What do I need to do to get this scanned doc to print?

Comment: Try opening the PDF in the default PDF viewer. First, using the print dialog print it into a new PDF file with an new name. Now open the newly created PDF file and see if it looks as expected. Then try to print the new file to your printer.

Comment: Thanks @user68186, nope same thing. It shows "Printing" then "Completed" but nothing from the printer. I am around the problem by taking a screen-shot then using GIMP to crop and then print. But, I'd still like to get this working for future use. I just booted to Mint 20.1 and it prints the same .pdf file fine.

Comment: You may want to file a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: goingB did you solve your problem, I have the same issue.